# How to save the multiple fields in dictionary using django views?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I want to save multiple fields in dictionary using django views.

My code:

```
promotions = Promotions.objects.filter(member = request.user)
list11 = []
dictt = {}
d = []
i = 0
for q in promotions:
    c = customer_request.objects.filter(promotion = q)
    e = c.count()
    d.append(e)
    dictt[e] = e
    list11.append(c)
    print("counttttttttttttttt", dictt)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

Code:
img_name = {}
img_name = {  'name':'xyz', 'type': 'jpg', 'path':'/temp/' }